# How to use .tflite model in android studio for image classification

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I am new Machine Learning and this is my first time making an android application for image classification of two species. I trained my keras model and then converted it to .tflite. I know want to use this file in android studio to detect two species i trained it on. I converted the model from keras to .tflite from this code:

```
tflite_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_model)
tflite_save = converter.convert()
open("my_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_save)
```

I know want to use the `my_model.tflite` file in android studio. I searched on internet but didn't get anything. Can someone help me in this problem. Thank you

Comment: So you did not find:  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/recognize-flowers-with-tensorflow-on-android/#0  Related: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=TensorFlow

Comment: Yes Sir, i saw this first time. can i use this method to upload my .tflite file to android studio for classification? sorry for my silly question i'm new to this field

Comment: The first link is a step-by-step tutorial. You should follow the tutorial first before trying your own code/data. Android Studio is an IDE not a cloud service so you don't upload to it. Pay attention to Step 5.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Sir,i have a bit problem in this code they said we need .txt file. but the code i showed above converted made 1 file from keras to tensorflow-lite

Comment: If you have two species you have two labels for your model. Modifying the code will require Java knowledge but lots of tutorials online covering that topic.

Comment: If you only have two labels for me there is no need for a .txt file...How is it going Mirza? Are you stuck?

Comment: @Farmaker Yes Sir, i'm stuck i don't know what will i do about the labels. Can you please help me

Comment: You have to help me a little bit and upload your android project to github. Send the link to my email

Comment: Ok, Sir what should i upload should i just upload the .tflite file?

Comment: No Mirza...upload the whole android project

Comment: Ok Sir, your name is George Soloupis?

Comment: yes Mirza add me to LinkedIn

Answer (score 2):

**Short term:** you can create a plain text file or have a string array [string array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StringArray) to store the two categories.

**Long term:** describe your model using tflite metadata which means it can be consumed by supporting tools such as Android Studio ML Model Binding and ML Kit.

**How to add TensorFlow Lite (tflite) metadata?** [Article](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/metadata) / [Sample code image classifier](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/metadata/metadata_writer_for_image_classifier.py)

Note: You get the metadata for free if you train your model with [TensorFlow Lite Model Maker](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification)

**How to consume TensorFlow Lite (TFLite) Model with metadata?**

- **Android Studio ML Model Binding** - supported from Android Studio 4.1 Beta 1 and up [(Codelab - step 5 onwards)](https://goo.gle/TFCodeLab) / [(Screencast - around 6 mins in onwards)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_XOVkjXQbU&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9znUgvI7lFPE-v5Vw4mGwG&index=5)[image: Android Studio 4.1 TensorFlow Model import dialog]
- **ML Kit Image Labelling with custom models** - [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/image-labeling/custom-models/android), [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart)

**Advanced topic**
If the object you are trying to classify does not take up the whole image - think scanning a leaf on the forest floor full of leaves or a single product on a super market shelf - it may be better to use [ML Kit Object Detection and Tracking with custom model](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/custom-models/android). It helps you crop a section of the image for processing, increasing the accuracy. Here's a [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RdEIXRgVHo&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9znUgvI7lFPE-v5Vw4mGwG&index=4) of how this works. [image: Custom bird identifier model used with ML Kit Object Detection and Tracking]

Comment: Thank you Sir i tried it on pc i have no webcam with pc so i thing thats why it gives blank screen. Sir, i am student of university. I just have to make simple classification of images of two species. my project is just to import an image from the gallery of mobile and it will classify it.

Comment: @Hoi your Screencast doesn't seem to describe the Long Term way for importing the Model but instead you use the asset folder. When I want to use the ML Kit Object Detection, how do I use it when I don't want to use the assets folder?

Comment: @bob, why is using the assets folder an issue? BTW you can use dynamic module delivery if you want to break down your app into multiple module.

Comment: @Hoi I was just wondering, as you use in the flower classify example the "File->New->Other->TensorFlow Lite Model"-way to import the model, if I can also use the Object Detection when importing the model that way instead of using the assets folder.

Comment: @Bob, Yes but it's not necessary. If you choose to use MLKit Object Detection, you won't need ML Model Binding and the binding classes it generates.

If you prefer ML model binding, there are also other kinds of object detection models such as this one (https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/ssd_mobilenet_v1/1/metadata/2). It detect the object as well as its location and you can use it on its own with ML Model binding (Studio 4.2+) and you won't need ML Kit.

Comment: To add to this, it's also possible to do this without metadata, at least with the current version of Android Studio (4.2.2), as I just went through the same conversion process and wasn't aware there was even an option to encode metadata.